# How can I select rows where keeping only those that meet this criteria? sql/hive

Tags: sql, hive

I have a table like the following:

```
+-------+------+
|ID     |lang  |
+-------+------+
|1      |eng   |  
|1      |pol   | 
|2      |eng   |  
|3      |gro   |
|3      |eng   |
+-------+------+
```

I'd like to keep only those rows where IF an ID is repeated i keep the non 'eng' row, so e.g. i would like:

```
+-------+------+
|ID     |lang  |
+-------+------+
|1      |pol   | 
|2      |eng   |  
|3      |gro   |
+-------+------+
```

is there a quick neat way i can achieve this?

Unsure how to go about this in a nice way to achieve result above! I am using hive

Comment: Can there be multiple non 'eng' rows for the same ID? If so then which one should be returned? Or is it always one 'eng' and one other language?

Comment: Yes there can be, but in that case i would just choose the first non eng one, it doesn't matter whic

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH cte_temp (Id, Lang, Rank) AS
(    
    SELECT 
        Id, Lang,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Id, LANG ORDER BY LANG DESC) AS Rank 
    FROM 
        YourTable
)
SELECT * 
FROM cte_temp 
WHERE rank = 1
```

Comment: This doesn't give me what i need, for ids where it has one english and one other language it return the english one

Comment: I have updated the code. Can you try it? I was doing order by ID desc which was not right we need LANG desc.

Comment: with this way, it doesnt actually filter out those ids with english (which have a non english langage too) - there is no differentiation between the ranks

Answer (score 0):

If you need single line per id, then use row_number(), partition by id, order by case statement in which you can have some custom ordering logic.

For example row_number below will mark any first not eng (randomly) row (per id) with rn=1, any other rows for the same id will be marked >1: 2, 3, 4... And you can filter only that single row. If you want to pick some lang preferably, add more cases to the case expression to order depending on lang, or you can add additional column or expression to the order by.

```
select id, lang
  from ( select id, lang,
                row_number() over(partition by id 
                                  order by case when lang != 'eng' then 1 
                                                else 2 
                                            end
                                 ) rn
        from mytable
       ) s
  where rn=1
```

If you need to keep all rows for the same id which are not 'eng', use `dense_rank()` or `rank()` instead of `row_number()` with the same over() as above, it will assign 1 to all rows with lang!='eng' per id.